# What is the proper way to say "queryer"

Tags: terminology

That is, the person who is querying.

The person who sends can be a *sender*, the person who receives can be a *receiver*.  Similarly the person who responds (to a query) can be a *responder*.

But can the person who queries be a *queryer*?

I've thought about using *initiator*, but I'd prefer something more specific.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is that you are spelling it wrong.  It's *querier*, not *queryer*.

Comment: *Query* is rather formal; *inquire* is more common and *ask* more common still → *inquirer*, *asker*. Or you could be really arcane and use *quærent* !

Comment: How much research have you done before asking here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm a researcher, but in computer science and engineering, not English, literature or linguistics.  I've exhausted the tools I'm aware of for this sort of thing, but admittedly, they're not many.  That being said, I'm nonetheless interested in the correct terminology.  Thanks for the concern.

Comment: "The one who's asking the question."

Comment: Check the [general references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/list-of-general-references) - now you have a whole new toolbox! :-)

Comment: A Google search for "query meaning" rapidly yields the [AHDEL entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/query) for 'query', which lists 'querier'. General reference.

Comment: If you are going to use the word in a technical context, and are looking for a concise way to say "the user who is entering a search query into our system", you should probably try to find a different way to describe him. In many cases, it is unambiguous to just say "the user", this is what information retrieval scientific articles say. If you want a good name for an object which initiates a query, then you don't need a word commonly recognized in everyday speech, a maintaining programmer will surely identify the purpose of an object called `SqlQuerier'.

Comment: You say kweer ee er.

Comment: Perhaps you should say "more query". ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't like *querier/queryer/queryist/querist* at all. A century or two ago, *querist* was actually quite common - but it's [massively declined since then](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=queryer%2Cquerier%2Cqueryist%2Cquerist%2C(querant%2Bquerent)&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquerier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquerist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28querant%20%2B%20querent%29%3B%2Cc0), and sounds seriously "Victorian" to me.

I'd go with ***querent*** (also sometimes spelled ***querant***) as the more "modern" usage...

[image]

EDIT: Also note from that chart (click on it to see the complete page which I can't reproduce here) that the forms *queryer, queryist* (spellings which were never common) are now both so rare they can't even be charted for the past half-century.

Comment: The OED confirms *querent*. The odd thing is that it also quotes *querist*, with the same meaning, but makes no attempt to link the two entries. It also offers the spelling*quaerent*. Etymology: post-classical Latin.

Comment: @WS2: I'm certainly glad your comment has made me look at this answer again! I originally just intended to rail against ***querist***, but then I edited in ***querier, queryer*** in the wrong place and mistakenly referenced ***querist*** as the first word I'd written even though it was by then the *last* in the list. Note that under ***querist***, OED says *compare earlier **querent***. Despite the implications of that "earlier", I still think ***querent*** is the form with most legs for the future.

Comment: @FumbleFingers
you said "and sounds seriously "Victorian". May I ask you whether you thi k it is a negative thing to employ such "victrian-ish" words/expressions in modern speech or not? Just curious as it's a part of my research. Thank you and I beg your pardon for the offtopic

Comment: @FumbleFingers The problem with the OED is that the same word can appear more than once. I was looking at *querist* as a derivative of *query*. In that particular place there is no reference to *querent*, as there is in the main entry on *querist*.

Comment: @WS2: Yes, but assuming you're accessing OED thru the same web UI as me, once you've located any specific word there's a scrollable alphabetized list panel on the right, centred on the current entry. So for *most* words, the derived forms are easily accessed from there.

Comment: _Querent_ was the word that most naturally popped into my head, but when I started looking, I found that neither ODO, AHDEL, nor (the free bits of) MW even had the word. I thought I was imagining things or going bonkers. Glad someone else agrees it's a good word for this. (There is the niggle with the Ngram that _querent_ can also mean ‘plaintiff’, so there's bound to be some false hits for that… but still!)

Comment: @Janus: As OED points out, ***querent*** can also have the specific sense *a person who consults an astrologer, fortune-teller, medium, etc.* It doesn't mention the legal sense specifically, but a few seconds on Google convinces me it *is* used in a sense that doesn't directly reflect the "base" meaning (unless you stretch a point to say the plaintiff is *querying* whether the legal system will hear/support his case).

Comment: Actually, the legal sense just reflects the older meaning of _quaesō/quaerō_ in Latin, which was ‘strive, endeavour, seek for’ (whence also its development to ‘wish for’ -> ‘desire’ -> ‘want/love’ in Spanish and Portugese), and the plaintiff in a case usually does strive for something. The meaning ‘ask’ is a later development in Latin, but in English, it seems _query_ itself was first borrowed with this sense, rather than the striving sense. So they're both quite ‘basic’, as it were, in what they reflect.

Comment: @Janus: Right. I keep forgetting how much meanings change over time. I should make a point of checking the etymology whenever I'm looking at an OED entry.

Comment: Apparently [*quaestor* was once much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quaestor%2Cquerier%2Cquerist%2C(querant+%2B+querent)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquaestor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquerier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquerist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28querant%20%2B%20querent%29%3B%2Cc0), but I’m betting these are all tax collectors.

Comment: *Querent* is definitely the one to go for, though all of them are better than *OP*.

Answer (score 10):

I would propose:

- ***inquisitor***
- ***inquirer***
- ***questioner***

Depending on the type of query you could be more specific as in ***auditor*** if the person is querying as part of an audit or auditing for example.

Comment: **Inquirer** or **enquirer** seems the best answer for the OP's question.

Comment: OP mentions usage is technical, in CS. "The database questioner" sounds slightly mental.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that you are spelling it wrong.  It's *[querier](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/querier)*, not *queryer*.  However, I would say that it's pretty esoteric, and may not be understood in writing as much as it would be in speech.

A more appropriate term that would be understood by the masses might be *[inquirer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inquirer)*.

Comment: Well, it kind of depends.  If I'm reading software documentation "querier" is much clearer in intent than "inquirer."

Answer (score 5):

The answer is *queryist* (which is now rare) or more recently ***querist*** (OED see below).

ˈqueryist   n. rare = querist n.

K. Sparck Jones & J. R. Galliers Evaluating Nat. Lang. Processing Systems i. 16 (table)    Role & category: queryist, habitual.

Answer (score 0):

Use the word "requester" or "questioner" instead.

Comment: Questioner has been mentioned already. Requester sounds very strange to my (native) ear.